# Magento 1.7 filter catalog products in view

Tags: ajax, magento, filter, categories

I want to filter a category product collection in frontend, and replace the products with the result collection i.e. the user is filtering by "blue" i want to filter the collection like addAttributeToFilter.

I want to do this with an ajax call, but i don't get what url i should use and where to perform this filtering.
Is the catalog list index controller accessable from url? Then i could work with get parameters here...

Or has somebody another solution how to manage this? I didn't really get how i.e. the sorter works and manipulates my collection, so i'm not able to adapt this behaviour in the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem with an ajax request out of list.phtml to the current URL adding parameters as data.
In Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php i modified the function _getProductCollection()
and added:

```
if($_POST['name']){
            $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$_POST['name'].'%'));
}
```

After the ajax request the products list table gets replaced with the filtered content.